# The tag [python35] is a duplicate of [python-3.5]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The "[python35](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python35/info)" tag is a poor man's "[python-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.5/info)" and should be removed.  There's not a [python27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python27), but there is a [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), and the prior is not a synonym of the latter, so I'm suggesting removal.

There are currently [0 questions on the Python 3-5 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python35/info), so I think this should be an easy one.

I've been told by a moderator that this tag will be cleaned up automatically and that it will just "disappear at some point in the future," but I ask "Where were you when I was submitting this question Jon?" and also "How are you? (good I hope)."

Comment: But… we might want to keep this for version 35…!

Comment: Features have not been laid out for version 35, but it's already rumored that it not be backwards compatible with version 34.9.

Comment: if it has 0 questions the tag will be removed at 03:00 UTC